# Making the Container less transparent and grey with these background Gradients

Tags: html, css, webkit

I copied css, from another site. I am not a css expert.
I have this css

```
.power-top-container {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 49%, rgba(204,204,204,0.95) 98%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(49%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9)), color-stop(93%,rgba(204,204,204,0.95)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 49%,rgba(204,204,204,0.95) 98%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 49%,rgba(204,204,204,0.95) 98%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 49%,rgba(204,204,204,0.95) 98%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 49%,rgba(204,204,204,0.95) 98%);
    padding: .8em 1.5em .8em 1.7em;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

and this html

```
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-10 large-10 large-centered columns">
                        <div class="power-container">
                            <div class="power-top-container">
                                <p class="">Quisque ante quam, imperdiet vitae velius. Donec ligula orci, posuere sed suscipit at, feugiat vel mi.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-10 large-5 columns">
                        <div class="power-container" style="">
                            <div id="" class="power-top-container">
                                <p>
                                    Quisque ante quam, imperdiet vitae velius. Donec ligula orci, posuere sed suscipit at, feugiat vel mi.
                                </p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-10 large-6 columns">
                            <div class="power-container" style="">
                                <div id="" class="power-top-container">
                                    <p>
                                        Quisque ante quam, imperdiet vitae velius. Donec ligula orci, posuere sed suscipit at, feugiat vel mi.
                                    </p>
                                    <img src="/PowerImages/cat.png" alt="cat Test Image" style="width:180px; height: 180px"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I figure a picture would better show you the gradient that is happening. [image: Gradient image becomes too see through] Notice how as the content reaches the lower right it becomes increasingly more transparent. I like the look of this, it is just too much. I tried changing some of the numbers and percentages a few times, but this seems a bit complex, and I can't seem to get anything to stop the right side becoming as transparent/grey as it is.

Additionally, can anyone provide any insight as to how these values effect the look of the content?

Comment: Are you sure you want a gradient then and not just a single background color?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it becomes less transparent as it reaches the lower right, it's an optical effet due to the color being darker.

The last value of rgba(r,g,b,a) color is the alpha, the lower is the value the more transparent it is.

If you want the color to become less grey then you can modify the "204" values to something higher.

I.e. : 
`background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 49%,rgba(235,235,235,0.95) 98%);`

Check this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) for complete informations about how css gradients are working.